# Trouble With Configuring IIS Express to accept external requests

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2013

I have been struggling for ages now. I am sure I am missing something silly.

I am Running 8.1 64bit with iis installed and Visual Studio 2013

I have done the following:

Disabled the firewall entirely.

`netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.100:5555/ user=everyone`

I have then located the IIS Config file in my Documents folder.
There was an already existing entry for my site it was as follows:

```
  <site name="FMAWebAPI.API(1)" id="12">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\Dylan\Dropbox\Work\FMA\Projects\Mobile Application\Web API\FMAWebAPI\FMAWebAPI" />
            </application>
            <bindings>                   
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5555:localhost" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

I then changed the binding to:

```
 <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:5555:*" />
```

However now when I run VS project I get an error:

```
The program '[5352] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1073741816 (0xc0000008) 'An invalid handle was specified'.
```

Comment: netsh isn't addressing the windows firewall.  Have you tried all these steps with the firewall totally disabled?

Comment: Firewall is disabled already, forgot to write it down.